# How do I loop through and animate nth-child one by one?

Tags: jquery

I want to animate a box (#timeUnit) to go to 100px, then go back to 0px, then another div (.fiveOne), I want nth-child(1) to disappear. Then, the box goes to 100px and back and nth-child(2) disappears. On and on 5 times.

In my code below, the box animates to 100, back to 0, then the nth-child(5) disappears, then the box animates to 100, back to 0, and no more nth-child boxes disappear! It's like the i evaluates to 5 before it runs.

```
$(function() {
 for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   $("#timeUnit").animate({width:100px},1000).animate({width:0},0,function(){
    $('.fiveOne .five:nth-child(' + i + ')').css({opacity:0});
   });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect you're getting happens because by the time the inner function runs, the for loop has completed and `i == 5`.

The way round this is to trap each value of i in a closure, like this :

```
$(function() {
    var $fiveKids = $('.fiveOne .five').children();
    function makeClosure(i) {
        return function() {
            $fiveKids.eq(i).css({opacity:0});
        }
    }
    for (var i=0; i<$fiveKids.length; i++) {
        $("#timeUnit").animate({'width':'100px'},1000).animate({width:0},0, makeClosure(i));
    }
});
```

Notes:

- `makeClosure()` is a function that returns a function, which is a bit mindblowing but quite normal in a language where functions are first class objects that can be passed around.
- The process is inefficient in that delay is introduced by repeating `$("#timeUnit").animate({'width':'100px'},1000)` in the loop. Personally , I would use a different approach entirely, but this version has been kept close to the original in this regard for clarity.

The expression `makeClosure(i)` is executed within the loop, trapping in turn each value of `i` in a closure and making the correct value of `i` available to the returned function when it eventually executes on completion of the second chained `.animate()`.

I think this will give the effect you want.

Edit: Code above corrected to accommodate @DavidThomas' point and to make it more efficient.

Comment: `:nth-child()` has a CSS, one-based, index not a JavaScript (and almost every other language I've heard of) zero-based index. So you should *probably* start `for (var i = 1; i<6; i++)`, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas, you're missing nothing. I was concentrating hard on getting the closure right and forgot about `:nth-child()` being index-origin ONE. Fixed above by using `.eq()` which works in index-origin ZERO and should be more efficient, especially with `$fiveKids` defined once in the outer scope.